# Django Wagtail Display children from parent inside another template page

Tags: html, django, wagtail

I have a model that looks like this

```
class StoryLinePage(ContentPage):
    body = StreamField([

        ('related_reports', blocks.PageChooserBlock(
            'content.ReportPage',
            icon='form',
            template='content/blocks/report_block.html')
         ),
    ], blank=True)
```

In that model I can render related reports with HTML, I would like to render `related_reports` but from the `ReportPage` model

```
class ReportPage(ContentPage):
    body = StreamField([
        ('heading', blocks.CharBlock(classname="full title")),
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
        ('dashboard', blocks.PageChooserBlock(
            'content.DashboardPage',
            icon='code',
            template='content/blocks/dashboard_block.html')
        ),
        ('table', TableBlock()),
    ], blank=True)

    search_fields = ContentPage.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('body'),
    ]

    content_panels = ContentPage.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        HelpPanel("", classname="edit-spacer"),
    ]
```

In `report_page.html`

I have access to `StoryLinePage` through django template tags

```
{% if page.related_storyline.all%}
    {% for story in page.related_storyline.all %}
    <div id='storylines'>
        <h4 class='storyline-header'>{{story.page.specific.title}}</h4>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I am trying to access `related_reports` within `ReportPage` but not sure where I am going wrong

```
 {% if page.related_storyline.all%}
    {% for story in page.related_storyline.all %}

    <div id='storylines'>
        <h4 class='storyline-header'>{{story.page.specific.title}}</h4>
        <div class="header-bar"></div>
        {% if page.related_storyline.related_reports.all%}
        {% for report in page.related_storyline.related_reports %}
        <a href={% pageurl story.page %} class="report-block-container">
        <div class="report-block-text">
            <p> {{report.page.specific.title}}</p>
        </div>
        </a>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</div>
```

At the moment, all that is rendering is the `storyline.page.title`, would appreciate any help

Thanks